# Powershell Script error

Tags: mvc, powershell-extensions, powershell

I am trying to import csv file to content data via power shell script.am getting following error message

```
    New-UsingBlock : Item '/sitecore/content/Web3/Content Shared 
    Folder/Property Page' is not in editing mode. Item ID: {A6E40603-D2E7- 
   4527-94B9-8B8F646E4574}
        At line:26 char:2
       +     New-UsingBlock (New-Object Sitecore.Data.BulkUpdateContext) {
       +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [New-UsingBlock], 
         EditingNotAllowedException
         FullyQualifiedErrorId:Sitecore.Exceptions.EditingNotAllowedException,Cognifide.PowerShell.Commandlets.Data.NewUsingBlockCommand
```

Did anyone came across this problem before and solved it? please help me 
also let me know for more info

```
            #Upload the file on the Server in temporary folder
             #It will create the folder if it is not found
             $TargetLanguage = "fr-CA"
              $Language = "en"

             $dataFolder = [Sitecore.Configuration.Settings]::DataFolder
             $tempFolder = $dataFolder + "/temp/upload"
             $filePath = Receive-File -Path $tempFolder -overwrite
             $templatePath = "Chartwell/Project/Website/Page 
              Template/Property Page"   #Here
                  $contentPath = "master:/content/Web3/Content Shared 
                 Folder/Property Page" #Here

              if($filePath -eq "cancel"){
           exit
             }

                $resultSet =  Import-Csv $filePath

              $rowsCount = ( $resultSet | Measure-Object ).Count;

            if($rowsCount -le 0){
          Remove-Item $filePath
    exit
}

Write-Log "Bulk Update Started!";
New-UsingBlock (New-Object Sitecore.Data.BulkUpdateContext) {
    foreach ( $row in $resultSet ) {
    $ItemName = $row."PropertyNameEn"; #Here


    $ItemNamePreClean  = $ItemName

    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "'"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "'", "";
    }
    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "ˆ"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "ˆ", " ";
    }
    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "\("){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "\(", " ";
    }
    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "\)"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "\)", " ";
    }

    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "à"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "à", "a" ;
    }
    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "á"){
    $ItemNamePreClean= $ItemNamePreClean -replace "á", "a";
    }
    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "â"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "â", "a";
    }
    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "À"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "À", "A";
    }
    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "Á"){
    $ItemNamePreClean= $ItemNamePreClean -replace "Á", "A";
    }
    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "Â"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "Â", "A";
    }

    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "é"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "é", "e";
    }
    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "è"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "è", "e";
    }
    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "ê"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "ê", "e";
    }
    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "ë"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "ë", "e";
    }
    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "É"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "É", "E";
    }

    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "ó"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "ó", "o";
    }
    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "ô"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "ô", "o";
    }
    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "Ó"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "Ó", "O";
    }
    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "Ô"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "Ô", "O";
    }

    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "î"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "î", "i";
    }
    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "ï"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "ï", "i";
    }
    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "Î"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "Î", "I";
    }
    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "Ï"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "Ï", "I";
    }

    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "ù"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "ù", "u";
    }
    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "û"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "û", "u";
    }
    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "Ù"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "Ù", "U";
    }
    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "Û"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "Û", "U";
    }

    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "æ"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "æ", "ae";
    }
    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "Æ"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "Æ", "AE";
    }

    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "ç"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "ç", "c";
    }
    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "Ç"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "Ç", "C";
    }

    if( $ItemNamePreClean -match "[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]"){
    $ItemNamePreClean = $ItemNamePreClean -replace "[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]", "";
    }

    $ItemName = $ItemNamePreClean
    $ItemName;
        $currentItem = New-Item $ContentPath -type $templatePath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Name $itemName -Language $Language 
        if ($currentItem){
            $currentItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
            $currentItem["Legacy ID"]= $row."PropertyID";   #Here
            $currentItem["Property ID"]= $row."PropertyID"; #Here
            $currentItem["Property Name"] = $row."PropertyNameEn";  #Here           
            $currentItem["Property Description"] = $row."PropertyDescEn";   #Here
            $currentItem["USP"] = $row."USP";   #Here
            $currentItem["Property Tag Line"] = $row."PropertyTagLineEn";   #Here
            $currentItem["Is owned"] = $row."IsOwned";  #Here
            $currentItem["Is Managed"] = $row."IsManaged";  #Here
            $currentItem["Is Leased"] = $row."IsLeased";    #Here
            $currentItem["Is Deleted"] = $row."IsDeleted";  #Here
            $currentItem["Is Featured"] = $row."IsFeatured";    #Here
            $currentItem["Is New Property"] = $row."IsNewProperty"; #Here
            $currentItem["Property Region"] = $row."PropertyRegion";    #Here
            $currentItem["Property Square Footage Max"] = $row."PropertySquareFootageMax";  #Here
            $currentItem["Property Square Footage Min"] = $row."PropertySquareFootageMin";  #Here
            $currentItem["Percent Share In Property"] = $row."PercentShareInProperty";  #Here
            $currentItem["Property Brochure Name"] = $row."PropertyBrochureName";   #Here
            #$currentItem["Property Brochure"] = $row."";   #Here
            $currentItem["Property Type"] = $row."";    #Here
            $currentItem["Property Type Description"] = $row."";    #Here
            $currentItem["Property Neighborhood"] = $row."NeighbourhoodID"; #Here
            #$currentItem["Property Seo Area"] = $row."";   #Here

        #Care Service Section
            $currentItem["Care Section Title"] = $row."";   #Here
            $currentItem["Care Section Description"] = $row.""; #Here


        #Dining Section
            $currentItem["Dining Section Title"] = "Dining Services";   #Here
            $currentItem["Dining Section Description"] = $row."DiningDataDesc"; #Here


        #WellnessData
            $currentItem["Wellness Section Title"] = "Wellness Services";   #Here
            $currentItem["Wellness Section Description"] = $row."WellnessDataDesc"; #Here


        #Activities Section
            $currentItem["Activities Section Title"] = "Activities Services";   #Here
            $currentItem["Activities Section Description"] = $row."ActivitiesDataDesc"; #Here


        #Amenities Section
            $currentItem["Amenities Section Title"] = "Amenities";  #Here
            $currentItem["Amenities Section Description"] = $row."AmenitiesDataDesc";   #Here


        #Address Section
            $currentItem["Street name and number"] = $row."StreetNameAndNoEn";  #Here
            $currentItem["Municipalty"] = $row."MunicipaltyEn"; #Here

            $currentItem["Postal code"] = $row."PostalCode";    #Here
            $currentItem["Longitude"] = $row."Longitude";   #Here
            $currentItem["Latitude"] = $row."Latitude"; #Here
            $currentItem["Is Display on Map"] = $row."IsDisplayInMap";  #Here




            #French Section
            $langAdd = Add-ItemLanguage -Item $currentItem -Language $Language -TargetLanguage $TargetLanguage -IfExist Skip;
            $currentItem.Editing.EndEdit();

            $ItemPath = $ContentPath + "\" + $itemName
            $NewcurrentItem = Get-Item -Path "master:" -Id $currentItem.id -Language $TargetLanguage
            $NewcurrentItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
            $NewcurrentItem["Property Name"] = $row."PropertyNameFr"; 
            $NewcurrentItem["Property Description"] = $row."PropertyDescFr";
                            $currentItem["USP"] = $row."USPFr"; 
            $NewcurrentItem["Property Tag Line"] = $row."PropertyTagLineFr"; 
            $NewcurrentItem["Property Brochure Name"] = $row."PropertyBrochureNameFr"; 
            $NewcurrentItem["Dining Section Title"] = $row."DiningDataTitleFr"; 
            $NewcurrentItem["Dining Section Description"] = $row."DiningDataDescFr"; 
            $NewcurrentItem["Wellness Section Title"] = $row."WellnessDataTitleFr"; 
            $NewcurrentItem["Wellness Section Description"] = $row."WellnessDataDescFr"; 
            $NewcurrentItem["Activities Section Title"] = $row."ActivitiesDataTitleFr"; 
            $NewcurrentItem["Activities Section Description"] = $row."ActivitiesDataDescFr"; 
            $NewcurrentItem["Amenities Section Title"] = $row."AmenitiesDataTitleFr"; 
            $NewcurrentItem["Amenities Section Description"] = $row."AmenitiesDataDescFr"; 
            $NewcurrentItem["Street name and number"] = $row."StreetNameAndNoFr"; 
            $NewcurrentItem["Municipality"] = $row."MunicipaltyFr";             


            $NewcurrentItem.Editing.EndEdit();
        }
        else {
            $logThis =  "Couldn't find: " + $ContentPath + "Item: " + $itemName;
            $logThis;
            Write-Log $logThis;
        }
    }
}
$logInfo = "Bulk Update is Completed!";
$logInfo
Write-Log $logInfo

  Remove-Item $filePath
```

Comment: and your script is...?

Answer (score 2):

In your script you first start with:

```
$currentItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
$currentItem["Legacy ID"]= $row."PropertyID";   
$currentItem["Property ID"]= $row."PropertyID"; 
# ...
# other $currentItem changes
# ...
# and then you finish editing $currentItem with line
$currentItem.Editing.EndEdit();
```

Then you start editing `$NewcurrentItem`:

```
$NewcurrentItem = Get-Item -Path "master:" -Id $currentItem.id -Language $TargetLanguage
$NewcurrentItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
$NewcurrentItem["Property Name"] = $row."PropertyNameFr";
```

but suddenly you edit `$currentItem` with this line. And `$currentItem` is not in editing mode anymore:

```
$NewcurrentItem["Property Description"] = $row."PropertyDescFr";
#
#
    $currentItem["USP"] = $row."USPFr"; # <--- THIS Line CAUSES ERROR
#
#
$NewcurrentItem["Property Tag Line"] = $row."PropertyTagLineFr";
```

It's line `$currentItem["USP"] = $row."USPFr";` which causes error

Comment: That's working but my csv data is not imported to the page.only page is created without any values

Comment: My answer updated to point you in which line you have bug

Answer (score 0):

It looks like somewhere inside your `using` block you try to update a field but you are not in editing mode.

One way to do this

```
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
$item.Fields["Title"].Value = "new title"
$item.Editing.EndEdit()
```

or

```
$item."Title" = "new title"
```

if you obtain an item in a different way than cmdlets (`Database.GetItem`) you will have to wrap an item to be able to access fields like properties

here is how to wrap your item

```
$item = $item | Wrap-Item
```